# Mutating an array declared with let keyword

Tags: swift

I get that `let` is used for constants and `var` is used for variables. However, this piece of code has confused me.

```
func filterGreaterThanValue(value: Int, numbers: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let result:[Int] = [Int]()

    for number in numbers {
        if number > value {
            result.append(number)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Running this yields the error

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:5:13: error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'result' is a 'let' constant
            result.append(number)
            ^~~~~~
```

To my understanding, an object declared with the `let` keyword is *immutable* in the sense that I can change its properties, but cannot reassign the variable pointing to that object to a different object (ie. have it point to another address in memory).

However, in this example I'm doing the same thing right? I've initialized an array object and I'm just modifying its properties. Why am I not allowed to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: But `Array` is not a class, is a struct...

Comment: If you add object in array then it should be mutable to do so . If you created array with let then it is constant just for reading purpose after assignment. it is normal behaviour in any programming language

Comment: side note: you can just a user a `where` clause on the `for` loop: `for number in numbers where threshold < number { result.append(number) }`

Comment: Further side note, you can just use `filter`: `return numbers.filter { threshold < $0 }`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Actually, most of the popular languages have arrays with reference semantics. For example, `readonly` and `final` (in C# and Java, respectively) ensure that a reference is not mutated, but they have no say over what happens to the object the reference... references.

Comment: @Alexander In Obj-C we have NSMutableArray & NSArray that is clearly differentiate which is mutable and which is not !!

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya There are immutable collections in C# and Java, too, but you miss my point. This immutability is enforced by the type, not by its decalaration as being `readonly`/`final`/`const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift `Array` is a `struct` which is value type. To change in the properties of struct you need to make both object and properties `var` type.